# Cross Product of specific file and rest of the folder -- R

Tags: r, loops, pattern-matching, filenames, cross-product

I have a problems making R read a set of files in a folder and returning cross product of them.

I have a folder which contains one test.csv file and n train.csv files.

I need a loop to read though on folder and return a file that contain the cross product of test and each of the train files… so the rows of file should look like this.

```
test*train01
test*train02
test*train03
...
```

I wrote a script to make that for two defined line but don’t know how to adapt that for the whole folder and the pattern that I need.

```
data01 <- as.matrix(read.csv(file = "test.csv", sep = ",", header=FALSE))
data02 <- as.matrix(read.csv(file = "train.csv", sep = ",", header=FALSE))
test <- list()
test01<- list()
test02<- list()
i<- 1
while (i <= 25){
    test01[[i]] <- c(data01[i,  ])
    test02[[i]] <- c(data02[i,  ])
    test[[i]]<- crossprod(test01[[i]],test02[[i]])
    i <- i+1
}
write.csv(test, file="testing.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
test <- function(data) {
data01 <- as.matrix(read.csv(file = "test.csv", sep = ",", header=FALSE))
data02 <- as.matrix(read.csv(file = data, sep = ",", header=FALSE))
test <- list()
test01<- list()
test02<- list()
i<- 1
while (i <= 25){
    test01[[i]] <- c(data01[i,  ])
    test02[[i]] <- c(data02[i,  ])
    test[[i]]<- crossprod(test01[[i]],test02[[i]])
    i <- i+1
}
return(test)
}

result <- lapply(list.files(pattern='Train.*'),test)
```

Then just loop `result` to save in CSV file.

EDIT: How to save:

```
files <- list.files(pattern='Train.*')
for (i in seq(length(result))) {
 write.csv(result[[i]], paste0('result_',files[i]), row.names = FALSE)
}
```

EDIT: Saving in one file:

```
write.csv(do.call(rbind,result),'result.csv', row.names = FALSE) # Appending by row
```

or

```
write.csv(do.call(cbind,result),'result.csv', row.names = FALSE) # Appending by column
```

Comment: And please do not grow your objects iteratively, preallocating them is much faster and memory efficient.

Comment: @Rcoster: So "data" reads all the files that are in a folder?
Tried 'write.csv(result, file="testing.csv", row.names = FALSE,  eol = "\n") but prints all of it as one row'

Comment: @Paul: Can you explain plz?

Comment: No, but `list.files(pattern='Train.*')` do; `data` is just a variable. Result is a list. I'll add how to write it in differents files.

Comment: @Rcoster: thanks a lot for your help... is there a way to print all of them in one file?

Comment: You continuously grow the objects using obj[[I]] = newstuff. Just create the object with the correct size, I.e. preallocate the object. This prevents continuous resizing of the object, which is very slow.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of the details

Comment: more questions: I am trying to run this for a set of files in a folder (two paths down) so tried '*/*/test.csv' but it is not working ? y? and I was wondering how can I get the whole or part of the path for the 'result.csv' as well? e.g. result-experiment01/test01.csv

Comment: `?list.files()`, parameters `recursive`, `all.names` and/or `include.dirs`.

Comment: can you explain more please?